# Parseplatform .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parse-platform

Trying to get started with Parse with .Net core. The server is already been created and all I need to do is to create the logins and queries. Using the SDK does not want to work, I need to use the 2.0.0-develop-1 as I need to include multiple headers in the initialize call which 1.7.0 does not include.

I am able to get login with the SDK and tis returns the user but the getting the current user or the session returns null. I can query the collections that are public but some of my collections have ACL for that user only, which returns null when I pass the query over.

I have tried using the RESTAPI and that does work, but when doing complicated queries it becomes a mission.

client.GetQuery("TestClass").WhereEqualTo("objectId", testObject.ObjectId).FirstAsync()) this returns null when not public.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
client.BecomeAsync(user.SessionToken);
```

Forgot to add this.